# Recover the value in an NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I want to recover the values contained in a NSDictionary.
I do this :

```
MyCommon *pCommon = [MyCommon Singleton];
NSArray *result = pCommon.res; //res is define and retain in common.m. This is the array.
NSDictionary *dataItem = [result objectAtIndex:????];
```

i don't know what i can put to replace the ????

Thanks

Comment: At what index is your dictionary?

Comment: Is `result` an array of NSDictionary ?

Comment: Need more information? Hard to see what you're trying to accomplish here. objectAtIndex takes an NSUInteger value.

Comment: Your question is how to retrieve values in a NSDictionnary but your code retrieves values (a NSDictionary) from an NSArray? Which one is the right "question"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, Objective-C makes a distinction between Arrays and Dictionaries.

An array is a collection, indexed by number. A dictionary is a collection indexed by objects (commonly strings, but can be other types).

On top of that, Objective-C makes a distinctions between mutable and immutable arrays and dictionaries. `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` cannot be modified after they are created. If you need to add objects to your collection, use `NSMutableArray` and `NSMutableDictionary` instead.

```
NSArray * myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"text1", @"text2", @"text3", nil];
// you can then access a member by using:
NSString * text = [myArray objectAtIndex: 0];

NSMutableDictionary * myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
// add an object
[myDict setObject:@"text1" forKey:@"key1"];
[myDict setObject:@"text2" forKey:@"key2"];
// you can retrieve objects using:
text = [myDict objectForKey: @"key1"];

[myArray release];
[myDict release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `result` is an `NSArray`, not an `NSDictionary`, so just put the index of the element you are interested in. Arrays are indexed by integers from zero.

In case your `result` is an `NSDictionary` and not an `NSArray`, use the `objectForKey:` method instead of `objectAtIndex:`.